# Prevent Trinidad from adding / overriding style properties in generated CSS

Tags: css, oracle-adf, trinidad

I'm working on an Apache Trinidad 1.2.14 project. I need to do some basic styling on a component (in my case `tr:breadCrumbs`). My problem is that Trinidad keeps adding and even overriding some style properties.

For example, this rule in my skin:

```
af|breadCrumbs { padding-bottom: 4px !important; }
```

is rendered in the resulting CSS file as:

```
.af_breadCrumbs { padding-bottom: 12px; display: table; }
```

My skin is extending `simple.desktop`:

```xml
<skin>
  <id>mySkin.desktop</id>
  <family>mySkin</family>
  <render-kit-id>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.desktop</render-kit-id>
  <style-sheet-name>_skin/mySkin.desktop.css</style-sheet-name>
  <extends>simple.desktop</extends>
</skin>
```

That is probably where the properties are coming from.

I even tried with [`-tr-inhibit: all`](https://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/devguide/skinning.html#Skinning_CSS_features), but that does not seem to be working.

> `-tr-inhibit` e.g., `af|foo {-tr-inhibit: padding; color: red}` This css property is used to inhibit/reset css properties that you are inheriting from a base skin.

How can this behavior be prevented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the strong feeling this is a bug. I was able to work around it using the following rule:

```
html af|breadCrumbs { padding-bottom: 4px; }
```

which is rendered in the resulting CSS file as:

```
html .af_breadCrumbs { padding-bottom: 4px; }
```